# Django Compare variables in template not working

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

So it may seem as a duplicate but none of the answers solve my issue.

So I'm using classed based views.
In context I'm sending something as active_country

```
                {{active_country}}
               <select class="country-link inputText span5">

                    <option value="all">All Countries</option>
                    {% for country in countries %}
                    <option value="{{ country.country_code }}" {% if active_country == country.name %} selected="selected" {% else %} not working {% endif %}>{{ country.name }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
```

But the if condition is never getting true. I even tried:

```
  {% if active_country == "Australia" %} selected="selected" {% endif %}
```

active country gives Australia but still condition does not get True.

And I have also tried:

```
  {% ifequal active_country "Australia" %} selected="selected" {% endifequal %}
```

I for sure know the active_country is being received right. I have printed it separately as well.

Can any one suggest whats wrong?

Comment: Check case sensitivity

Comment: What is active_country? How is it defined and how is it passed to the template?

Comment: @DanielRoseman ok. Just this question of yours solved my problem. active_country is an object.
Should have used active_country.name

Comment: @user2156936 If you have come to the solution to your problem, please leave it as an answer for the next fellow who comes along.

Comment: @cwallenpoole sure I will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm answering my one question.  The error I was making:

active_country is an object. Hence I should be using active_country.name

I was getting all confused as just {{active_country}} was also giving the name. This was because the unicode was set to name in my models.py